# How to inherit getInputFilterSpecification method for nested fieldsets in ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-inputfilter, zend-form-fieldset

I am developing input filters in the fieldset classes for a ZF3 module using a class-table inheritance pattern.  The [ZF3 documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/quick-start/#hinting-to-the-input-filter) says that the fieldset class must implement `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface`, which defines a `getInputFilterSpecification()` method.

```
namespace Contact\Form;

use Zend\Filter;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Validator;

class SenderFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => Filter\StringTrim::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => Validator\StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 256
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'email' => [
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => Filter\StringTrim::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    new Validator\EmailAddress(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

This works fine for independent fieldset classes, but if I have one fieldset extend another fieldset, the form uses the `getInputFilterSpecification()` method from the child only.

```
namespace Contact\Form;

use Zend\Filter;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Validator;

class PersonFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => Filter\StringTrim::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => Validator\StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 256
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}

class SenderFieldset extends PersonFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'email' => [
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => Filter\StringTrim::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    new Validator\EmailAddress(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Since the `getInputFilterSpecification()` method is just a collection of return statements, I thought I could add a call to the parent method within the child method, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
// in child:

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

        parent::getInputFilterSpecification();

    // ...
```

How can I get the `getInputFilterSpecification()` method in the child fieldset to inherit the code from the `getInputFilterSpecification()` method from the parent?

Comment: I think you just need add `return` on that method `return parent::getInputFilterSpecification();`

Comment: is missing `return` the problem?

Comment: `return parent::getInputFilterSpecification();` did the trick,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dolly Aswin's comment, here is the answer:

```
namespace Contact\Form;

use Zend\Filter;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Validator;

class PersonFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => Filter\StringTrim::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => Validator\StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 256
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}

class SenderFieldset extends PersonFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

        // get input filter specifications from parent class
        return parent::getInputFilterSpecification();

        return [
            'email' => [
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => Filter\StringTrim::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    new Validator\EmailAddress(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but this will not work as the second array will not be returned. To do this you need `return array_merge(parent::getInputFilterSpecification(), [ // you email filter array ]);`